# executar um arquivo javascript quando o usuário acessar uma rota node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho a rota / no meu server.js:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("public/index.html", {root: __dirname})
})
```

E preciso executar outro arquivo javascript que está no mesmo diretório (ou executar a função que está contida nele) ao acessar a rota / antes de renderizar o html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você importar a função desse arquivo e chamar em sua rota. Exemplo:

```
const minhaFuncao = require('./minhaFuncao.js');

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    minhaFuncao();
    res.sendFile("public/index.html", {root: __dirname})
})
```

Obs: seu arquivo `minhaFuncao.js` deve esar **exportando** a sua função

Comment: há alguma exceção p funções async? pq aparentemente meu server.js n esta executando a função...

Comment: Não. Você apenas deve utilizar o `async/await` que funcionará

Answer (score 0):

Se vc quer executar essa função no html, vc pode usar o PUBLIC do express.

```js
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/sua-pasta"))
```

Com ele vc consegue rotear uma pasta no diretório do servidor, e no html, basta vc colocar no final da url **"./nome-do-arquivo.js"** para dar request.

No caso, no html ficaria

```html
    <script scr='./nome-do-arquivo.js'></script>
```

aí é só colocar isso logo após a tag `<body>` pra abrir antes de carregar a página!!